# Dataverse extract choices names/values list

Tags: azure-data-factory, dataverse

I'm working on migration data to Dataverse by ADF and currently destination tables have a bunch of Choices fields, which IDs (values) I need to consider during source dataset generation to map them accordingly in the ADF p ipeline.
Is there a possibility to extract Choices field data in readable name/value pairs?

E.g. for MonthOfYear retrieve
Invalid Month Of Year 0
January 1
February 2,.. etc
[image]

I'm able to query tables via SSMS, but seems Choices are different story how to get them. Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The metadata can be retrieved by this link:
https://yourorgname.crm4.dynamics.com//api/data/v9.0/GlobalOptionSetDefinitions

All queries return a JSON, like any REST api, then it can be loaded and parsed within SQL Server.